# Is there a way to make cell default-click or make the edit mode without click in react-bootstrap-table-2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

[image]

For example, I have a Select cell. When user chose 'Edit' mode, I want him to see that this cell is editable. But as I understand, react-bootstrap-table-2 allows edit only by click.

```
    const columns = [    
          ...
         {
                text: 'RESULT',
                dataField: 'result',
                editorRenderer: (editorProps, value, row, column, rowIndex, columnIndex) => (
                    <CustomSelect { ...editorProps } rowIndex={rowIndex} value={ value } />
                )
       

     },
]

return (
<BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={data} columns={columns}
                                hover condensed rowClasses={rowClass} bordered={ false }
                                cellEdit={ cellEditFactory({ mode: 'click', blurToSave: true }) }> </BootstrapTable>
)
```

Is there a way to override this 'click' mode?